# Django REST Framework browsable API error when using different serializers for different HTTP methods

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have to create an API for an existing Django based web app and I'm using DRF to do so. Although I've never used DRF before, everything was incredibly clear and fine until I ran into this problem. Here's the URL in question:

```
http://www.<customer-website-name>.com/api/friendship-requests/<sender-pk>/
```

According to the requirements spec that I was given, it's supposed to be handled like this:

- [GET] Return a `FriendshipRequest` object that was sent to the currently authenticated user by a user whose `pk = <sender-pk>` or 404 if such request doesn't exist.
- [PUT] Accepts an `AcceptReject` object (e.g., JSON `{"accepted": false}`). If `accepted == True`, clean up `FriendshipRequest`, create a new `Friendship` object, return 201; if `accepted == False`, mark `FriendshipRequest` as rejected, return 204

Here's the `AcceptReject` class and it's serializer:

```
class AcceptReject(object):
    def __init__(self, accepted):
        self.accepted = accepted

class AcceptRejectSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    accepted = serializers.BooleanField()
```

This is the view I'm using to handle the url:

```
class FriendshipRequestDetail(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
            generics.GenericAPIView):

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'PUT':
            return serializers.AcceptRejectSerializer
        return serializers.FriendshipRequestSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        sender = generics.get_object_or_404(get_user_model(),
                pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        obj = generics.get_object_or_404(FriendshipRequest, 
                from_user=sender,
                to_user=self.request.user)

        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)

        return obj

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

I naively thought that overriding `get_serializer_class()` to return a serializer based on request method would be enough, but it wasn't.

Also, as you can see, I haven't even started writing the PUT handler. Just it's presence is enough to cause the following error when I try to use the browsable api:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/friendship-requests/5/

Django Version: 1.8.4
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.gis',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework.authtoken',
 'friendship',
 'REDACTED.REDACTED')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/manvis/REDACTED/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  164.                 response = response.render()
File "/home/manvis/REDACTED/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  158.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "/home/manvis/REDACTED/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py" in rendered_content
  71.         ret = renderer.render(self.data, media_type, context)
File "/home/manvis/REDACTED/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py" in render
  669.         context = self.get_context(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
File "/home/manvis/REDACTED/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py" in get_context
  614.         raw_data_put_form = self.get_raw_data_form(data, view, 'PUT', request)
File "/home/manvis/REDACTED/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py" in get_raw_data_form
  561.                 content = renderer.render(serializer.data, accepted, context)
File "/home/manvis/REDACTED/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  487.         ret = super(Serializer, self).data
File "/home/manvis/REDACTED/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  223.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
File "/home/manvis/REDACTED/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
  447.                 attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)
File "/home/manvis/REDACTED/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py" in get_attribute
  418.             raise type(exc)(msg)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /api/friendship-requests/5/
Exception Value: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `accepted` on serializer `AcceptRejectSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `FriendshipRequest` instance.
Original exception text was: 'FriendshipRequest' object has no attribute 'accepted'.
```

Like I've said, it's my first time using DRF, but, if I understood the trace correctly, it seems that the error stems from DRF trying to render the form for the browsable api, unfortunately, I can't go without it, because a browsable api is also a requirement.

What else do I need to change/override in order to get browsable api working for this view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems comes from the fact, that you break REST convention. Instead of resource representation you use action in `PUT` request. In the REST you would rather have `is_accepted` or `state` field inside your `FriendRequest` object and by modification of this field you would accept or reject requests. I highly recommend you to point on this to designers of your spec.

In the browsable API DRF generates a form to update record, so it gets serializer by calling `get_serializer()` (which returns `AcceptRejectSerializer`) and transforms this serializer into form. Then it gets record by calling `get_object()` (which returns `FriendshipRequest` object) and tries to fill form with data got from the record. Obviously fields in record and serializer doesn't match, so you get an error.

As a shitty solution you can add `accept` attribute inside `get_object()` method:

```
def get_object(self):
    sender = generics.get_object_or_404(get_user_model(),
            pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
    obj = generics.get_object_or_404(FriendshipRequest, 
            from_user=sender,
            to_user=self.request.user)

    self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)

    obj.accept = False

    return obj
```

Or add it as into `FriendshipRequest` model:

```
class FriendshipRequest(...):
    # ...

    accept = False
```

Or you can try to [override `view`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/#advanced-customization) to skip form filling step.

Comment: Even after your suggested modification, I still get the same error.

Comment: It means that `get_object()` is called with `GET` request, when rendering browsable API (my assumption failed). As a shitty solution you can try to replace lines from answer with `obj.accept = False` or add `accept = property(lambda: False)` to the `FriendshipRequest` model. Otherwise, you can try to [override `view`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/#advanced-customization) to skip form filling step. But as I said the whole problem is that you're breaking REST convention and doing things DRF doesn't support.

Comment: I went with the `obj.accepted = False` solution. I know that this is breaking REST conventions, but, according to the person who designed the spec, this web app was originally made without even considering the possibility of adding an API at a later date. He also said he was trying to map the functionality of [Django-Friendship](https://github.com/revsys/django-friendship/) library (which provides the friendship functionality and all models) to the API requests.

Comment: Okey, that's up to you. Maybe having it as clear action routes is a better alternative... E.g. `/api/friendship-requests/<sender-pk>/accept/` and `/api/friendship-requests/<sender-pk>/reject/`.